# Multiplying variables and showing result in a box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a problem when trying to multiply the totalPallets by the price-per-pallet ($25) and then showing that in the productSubTotal box. With the code as it is right now, the quatity total shows but when I try to get the price result, it doesn't show the operation. Also, if I try changing anythung from the code, the whole thing breaks down. I'll be thankful if anyone could help me. Thanks

```
// UTILITY FUNCTIONS 

function IsNumeric(n) {
    return !isNaN(n);
}

function calcTotalPallets() {
    var totalPallets = 0;
    $(".num-pallets-input").each(function() {
        var thisValue = parseInt($(this).val());
        if ( (IsNumeric(thisValue)) &&  (thisValue != '') ) {
            totalPallets += parseInt(thisValue);
        };
    });
    $("#quantitytotal").val(totalPallets);
}

function calcProdSubTotal() {
    var prodSubTotal = 0;
    $(".totalprice").each(function() {
        var valString = parseInt(totalPallets) * multiplier;
        prodSubTotal += parseInt(valString);
    });
    $("#product-subtotal").val(CommaFormatted(prodSubTotal));
};


// "The Math" is performed pretty much whenever anything happens in the quanity inputs
$('.num-pallets-input').bind("focus blur change keyup", function(){
    // Caching the selector for efficiency 
    var $el = $(this);

    // Grab the new quantity the user entered
    var numPallets = CleanNumber($el.val());
    var totalPallets = CleanNumber($el.val());
    var prodSubTotal = CleanNumber($el.val());

    // Find the pricing
    var multiplier = $el
        .parent().parent()
        .find("td.price-per-pallet span")
        .text();
    };
    // Calcuate the overal totals
    calcProdSubTotal();
    calcTotalPallets();    
});
function CommaFormatted(amount) {
    var delimiter = ","; 
    var i = parseInt(amount);
    if(isNaN(i)) { return ''; }
    i = Math.abs(i);
    var minus = '';
    if (i < 0) { minus = '-'; }
    var n = new String(i);
    var a = [];
    while(n.length > 3)
    {
        var nn = n.substr(n.length-3);
        a.unshift(nn);
        n = n.substr(0,n.length-3);
    }
    if (n.length > 0) { a.unshift(n); }
    n = a.join(delimiter);
    amount = "$" + minus + n;
    return amount;
}

});
```

Comment: Try "debugging" your program. Step through it. Place breakpoints. Examine variables. I doubt if anyone here is going to take the time to sift through this long piece of code.

Comment: I edited it to include only what I think is relevant. Could you please check it out? Thank you.

Comment: No, I can't. Please try debugging your program first. If you have questions about how to debug, and can't find the answers through normal means, or get stuck, then please post that as a separate question "How to debug in blah blah situation".

Comment: fyi: you have some floating brackets and parenthesis in your code, (ie "find the pricing" section)

Comment: I've debugged it and it shows no error and no floating brackets

Comment: It could easily be a logic error, try introducing simple logging to your code at as many points as you need to fish out the error

Comment: thank you! I'll try that and see what happens